# What am I supposed to do with Level 4 in Vim Adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

I acquired the candle and went back to the location where I was supposed to.
Then I was asked something like "help us: it's our darkest hour."
So, I am not sure what I am supposed to do next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After you get the candle, and find the princess who says "it's our darkest hour", just press **j** to go down three times.  Then the lights come back on, and you see the next editing challenge.